# How does Sidekiq passes arguments to the perform method?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I have this Sidekiq worker:

```
class DealNoteWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :email

  def perform(options = {})
    if options[:type] == "deal_watch_mailer"
      deal_watchers = DealWatcher.where("deal_id = ?", options[:deal_id])

      deal_note = DealNote.find(options[:deal_note_id])

      current_user = User.find(options[:current_user_id])

      deal_watchers.each do |deal_watcher|
        unless deal_watcher.user_id == options[:current_user_id]
          # Tell the DealWatchMailer to send emails to ALL watchers advising of change to deal
          if deal_watcher.user.active
            DealWatchMailer.deal_watch_email(deal_watcher, nil, deal_note, current_user, options[:url]).deliver
          end
        end
      end
    elsif options[:type] == "deal_note_mailer"
      options[:user_ids].each do |id|
        if DealWatcher.where("deal_id = ? and user_id =?", options[:deal_id], id).count == 0
          deal_note = Deal.find(options[:deal_note_id])
          user = User.find_by_id(id)
          DealNoteMailer.deal_note_email(deal_note, user, options[:url]).deliver
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I pass a hash to the `perform_async` method, but I think that the parameters transfered to the `perform` method are not of the same type as the ones passed to `perform_async`. I tried to user `logger.info` and `p` to debug my issue but nothing gets outputted...

The issue is that the job is added to the email queue but never gets processed. I even tried to raise an exception in the `perform` method (on the first line of the method) but nothing was outputted either...

I know as a fact that the following worker works:

```
class DealNoteWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(deal_id, deal_note_id, current_user_id, url)
    deal_watchers = DealWatcher.where("deal_id = ?", deal_id)

    deal_note = DealNote.find(deal_note_id)

    current_user = User.find(current_user_id)

    deal_watchers.each do |deal_watcher|
      unless deal_watcher.user_id == current_user_id
        # Tell the DealWatchMailer to send emails to ALL watchers advising of change to deal
        if deal_watcher.user.active
          DealWatchMailer.deal_watch_email(deal_watcher, nil, deal_note, current_user, url).deliver
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So the problem lies in the hash parameter (options). What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: You sure that you've started the sidekiq workers? Run `bundle exec sidekiq` in another terminal. Also, you're using a queue called `email`, so you'll need to run `sidekiq -q email`.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. I needed to start sidekiq with the email queue. So I added a list of queues in a sidekiq.yml config file and that fixed the problem. Could you add your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 34):

From the [Sidekiq documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-jobs-input-small-and-simple):

> The arguments you pass to perform_async must be composed of simple
>   JSON datatypes: string, integer, float, boolean, null, array and hash.
>   The Sidekiq client API uses JSON.dump to send the data to Redis. The
>   Sidekiq server pulls that JSON data from Redis and uses JSON.load to
>   convert the data back into Ruby types to pass to your perform method.
>   Don't pass symbols or complex Ruby objects (like Date or Time!) as
>   those will not survive the dump/load round trip correctly.

You can see this on the console:

```
> options = { :a => 'b' }
> how_sidekiq_stores_the_options = JSON.dump(options)
> how_sidekiq_loads_the_options = JSON.load(how_sidekiq_stores_the_options)
> how_sidekiq_stores_the_options == how_sidekiq_loads_the_options
  false
```

It looks like you are using symbols as the keys for your `options` hash. If you switch to string keys, it should work.

Comment: Also note that Hashes can be problematic. Passing these as JSON solved a mysterious "wrong number of arguments" error for me.

Comment: I've got something similar. The first time the worker runs I get an exception that my code raises, the next retry I get the wrong number of argument error.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a queue called email, so you'll need to run sidekiq -q email.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that hash keys sent as symbols will be converted to strings in the transfer to Sidekiq perform.